# Modeling VS Programming

Tags: computer-science, modeling

This might be a general Computer Science question but the benefit of the question, what's the difference between Modelling and Programming? How are they approached both separately and combined?

Moderators, instead of locking or closing this general question, help me out (commenting) to broaden down this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference are as follow

Modeling:
Modelling is a scientific activity the aim of which is to make a particular part or feature of the world easier to understand

Programming:
This describes how to struct/build the model using real world objects or abstract concepts. with the help of programming, simulation of model can be construct and this helps more to understand the modeling features

Comment: Modelling must come first before programming? Can there be a situation /case that modelling and programming are separated?

Comment: Generally model is created before programming and it is highly recommended first model and then do programming. In prototype, modeling and programming is separated. In computer science prototype concept is different for other Engineering core